# How to resolve this error "Database server does not support the InnoDB storage engine." when i install magento?

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, error

I try to install magento in windows 8 64bits with wamp server but when i am in configuration step i have this error "Database server does not support the InnoDB storage engine."
How can i resolve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable it in my.cnf file, then restart your server:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-parameters.html#option_mysqld_innodb

Or you can load an InnoDB plugin during runtime:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replacing-builtin-innodb.html